# Remove Inserted HTML Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering how I would remove code that appears after I select a certain Radio Button.  I have got it to generate but when I remove it the whole body disappears so, I would need to only remove the fragment.

```
<head>
    <style>
        input, label {
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="modtype" value="My Mods" id="mymods">
            <label for="orange">My Mods</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="modtype" value="Group Mods" id="groupmods">
            <label for="apple">Group Mods</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="modtype" value="Individual Mods" id="individualmods">
            <label for="banana">Individual Mods</label>
        </div>
        <div id="modtype"></div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $("input").on("click", function() {
            $("#modtype").html($("input:checked").val() + " is selected! - Now Choose Mod! :)");
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        var appended = $('<div />').text('YOYOY');
        var fragment = create('<div>Hello!</div><p>...</p>');

        appended.id = 'appended';

        $('input:radio[name="modtype"]').change(

        function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'My Mods') {
                document.body.insertBefore(fragment, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            } else {
                document.body.remove(fragment);
            }
        });

        function create(htmlStr) {
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
while (temp.firstChild) {
    frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
}
return frag;
}
    </script>
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Careful when injecting elements via `innerHTML`. Not only will it make it harder to get newly generated content out of wherever it was placed, but a slew of other problems can occur (event listeners breaking, selectors breaking due to bad markup, etc.) You should (almost) always add elements with `appendChild` or `insertBefore`. I'll leave the answer to a jQuery expert that knows how to do this through the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your code, I have tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gJk7J/

Simply change:
`document.body.remove(fragment);`
To:
`if(fragment.parentNode)fragment.parentNode.remove(fragment);`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using `.remove()` correctly.  You need to find your fragment, get it into a jQuery object and then call `.remove()` on that jQuery object.

Assuming, there is only one fragment with the id you've given it, it can be as simple as this:

```
$("#appended").remove();
```

to remove the fragment that you gave the `id="appended"` to.

Or, if you still have the DOM element that's the root of what you want to remove, you can do this:

```
$(fragment).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are asking, this is how I remove some elements-- you need to know the name of div which you want to remove.  See code below, and change to your values

```
 var removeDiv= document.getElementById("your-div-id");
                if (typeof removeDiv !== "undefined"){
                    if (removeDiv !==  null){                    
                        document.getElementById('your-root-div-id').removeChild(removeDiv);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

When you did it:

```
document.body.insertBefore(fragment, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

the elements in the fragment's childnodes were became to the childnodes of document.body.So the fragment have no childnodes any more. You have to find the elements which you create(jQuery or getElementxxxxxs) and remove them.

2.

The way you want to remove the element from body is not correct.

```
document.body.remove(fragment);
```

you can do it like these:

```
document.body.removeChild(someChildNode); // dom api
$([elem/selector]).remove();              // jQuery
```